# Angular Custom Directive SEO Concerns and Questions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, seo

I read opposing answers to the general question "does Angular affect SEO?" and "do search engines crawl Angular apps?"

I would like clarification for all who use Angular and want to effectively develop for good SEO. Specifically, I am wondering about the way I use Angular.

Here is an example of a site I am building using Angular: http://www.lancebeaudry.com/ias/industrial-ventilation.html

I use custom directives to add the nav bar and footer on every page, and then, on the page from the link provided, I am using the Angular search filter within a custom directive. My biggest question/concern is:

Are search engines going to be able to crawl and understand the content in the directives, especially the content (which includes anchor text and links) in my search function?

Using Google Web Master Tools "Fetch and Render as Google" it just shows the custom directive tags, not the content within them. This leads me to believe it's not being crawled - however, I know Google does in fact crawl content from JS and CSS. (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html)

Here is the code from the page as it is written (inspecting in the browswer will of course show you the content still):

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">        
<div class="box" id="search-box">
    <h2>Search Manufacturers, Solutions, Equipment, Etc.</h2>
    <input type="search" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div> 
<div class="row">
    <manufacturer info="awv" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="flexcom" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="kpi" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="usduct" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="rodair" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="sopers" search="search"></manufacturer>
    <manufacturer info="enertech" search="search"></manufacturer>

</div><!-- /row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Since the middle of October, Google won't have any problems with your application. But of course Bing and others will have. Google has more than 90% of the searching market share, so if you don't mind about the others, you won't have a problem there.